# Silverlight Change image source nested inside button

Tags: silverlight, xaml, button

For a button image like below how do i change the source of the image on button click

```
    <Button Name="btnFullScreen" Width="32" Height="32" Click="BtnFullScreenClick">
        <Image Source="img/fs.png" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
    </Button>
```

there doesn't seem to be a property like btnFullscreen.Controls (I come from asp.net background hence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `Content` property.

```
private void BtnFullScreenClick(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Image img = ((Button)sender).Content as Image;
        img.Source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new System.Uri("newImage.jpg", System.UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Comment: Content never flashed me, i was thinking about child controls and other stuff. It just tries to impose try to be simple always thanks :)